# Value of k so that a linear system is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I solve this problem.
Give a value of    so that the linear system below is consistent. Thank you.

$x - 2y = 4$,     $3x - 6y = k$

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've tried and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Divide the second equation by $3$. What do you notice?

Comment: dividing the second equation by 3 gives x - 2y = k. Except for the k it looks the same as the first.

Comment: Dividing $3x-6y=k$ by $3$ gives $x-2y=\frac{k}{3}.$ From the first you also know that $x-2y=4$, so what $k$ can we choose such that the system is consisent?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Helped me understand.